# Importing of Neo4j DB (1.9.4) into Gephi (0.8.2) with plugin (1.0.2) - "An error Occured while feching data"

Tags: neo4j, gephi

OS: Windows 7

I have a Problem importing Neo4j DB into Gephi.

When i've done a Full Import, I get this error 
"An error Occured while feching data"

the same thing got asked here
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/1327rse2nf/problem-importing-neo4j-db-into-gephi

Has anyone seen or found an update or resolution on this?

Thanks j

Update: Looking for Logs
I found this http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/HowTo_report_a_bug - but the directories it points you to are not there.

C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming.gephi(gephi_version)dev\var\log\message.log

Comment: Can you find any details in the Gephi logs?

Comment: I haven't looked (i will now that you mention it). Can you point me at where they might be?

Comment: Unfortunately not, perhaps ask on the gephi mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it using a toolkit that can export all data from Neo4J as a GraphML file and then open it in Gephi.

For example, see https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools